# Repeat input audios while mixing

Tags: ffmpeg

I have Two audio , `short1.mp3` and `short2.mp3`

I want to loop `short1.mp3` for 100 times and also loop `shor2.mp3` until  duration of `short1.mp3(100 times looped)` .How can I do it , Below is the Code I tried

```
ffmpeg -i short1.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=short2.mp3:loop=100[s];[0][s]amix=duration=shortest" final.mp3
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex "amovie=short1.mp3:loop=100[r];amovie=short2.mp3:loop=0[s];[r][s]amix=duration=shortest" final.mp3
```

You will likely get DTS errors, but check output, which should be fine.

---

You can also 'precompose' the looped files.

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 100 -i short1.mp3 -c copy short1-100.mp3

ffmpeg -stream_loop 500 -i short2.mp3 -c copy short1-500.mp3

ffmpeg -i short1-100.mp3 -i short2-500.mp3 -filter_complex amix=duration=shortest final.mp3
```

Comment: Hi , I get lots of errors like [mp3 @ 0x231c460] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 531072 >= 513590
 , how can I avoid it ,, It is making the process too slow

Comment: It won't slow down the process, and the output file should be fine,

Comment: You can change `9999` to `0` if you want it to loop infinitely.

Comment: Thanks. Done. That's a counter-intuitive value, though.

Comment: It is slow , I use this method now .. sox audio.mp3 audio-loop.mp3 repeat 100 &&  ffmpeg -y -i audio-loop.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=bg.mp3:loop=200[s];[0][s]amix=duration=first" final.mp3 ..

Comment: Can you Give me ffmpeg for this command sox audio.mp3 audio-loop.mp3 repeat 100  .. which is basically looping the input audio 100 times ..  I believe it will be fast in ffmpeg rather than Sox

Comment: See alt method.

Comment: @Mulvya Yeah, and to make things more confusing `-stream_loop` uses `-1` instead.